# Compare each row of Pandas df1 with every row within df2 and return string value from closest matching column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames.

df1 includes 4 men and 4 women with their weight and height (inches).

```py
#df1
John, 236, 76
Jack, 204, 74
Jim, 156, 71
Jared, 182, 72
Suzy, 119, 60
Sally, 149, 66
Sharon, 169, 65
Sammy, 182, 75
```

df2 includes 4 men and 4 women with their weight and height (inches).

```py
#df2
Aaron, 285, 77
Abe, 236, 75
Alex, 178, 72
Adam, 195, 71
Mary, 148, 66
Maylee, 155, 66
Marilyn, 199, 65
Madison, 160, 73
```

What I am trying to do is have men from df1 be compared to men from df2 to see who they are most like based on height and weight.  Just subtract weight from weight and height from height and return an absolute value for each man in df2. More specifically, return the name of the man most similar.

So in this case John's closest match is Abe so in a new column
`df1['doppelganger'] = "Abe"`.

I'm a beginner hobbyist so even pointing me in the right direction would be helpful. I've been looking through stack overflow for about five hours trying to figure out how to go about something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary distinguish `men` and `women`, here is used new column with repeat 4 times `m` and `f`. Then is used [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join by new column for all combinations and created new columns for differences, last column is `sum` of them. then sorting by 3 columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), so first row per groups by `A` and `g` are filtered by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df1.assign(g = ['m']*4 + ['f']*4)
          .merge(df2.assign(g = ['m']*4 + ['f']*4), on='g', how='outer', suffixes=('','_'))
          .assign(dif1 = lambda x: x['B'].sub(x['B_']).abs(),
                  dif2 = lambda x: x['C'].sub(x['C_']).abs(),
                  sumdiff = lambda x: x['dif1'] + x['dif2'])
          .sort_values(['A', 'g','sumdiff'])
          .drop_duplicates(['A','g'])
          .sort_index()
          .rename(columns={'A_':'doppelganger'})
          )
print (df)
         A    B   C  g doppelganger   B_  C_  dif1  dif2  sumdiff
1     John  236  76  m          Abe  236  75     0     1        1
7     Jack  204  74  m         Adam  195  71     9     3       12
10     Jim  156  71  m         Alex  178  72    22     1       23
14   Jared  182  72  m         Alex  178  72     4     0        4
16    Suzy  119  60  f         Mary  148  66    29     6       35
20   Sally  149  66  f         Mary  148  66     1     0        1
25  Sharon  169  65  f       Maylee  155  66    14     1       15
31   Sammy  182  75  f      Madison  160  73    22     2       24
```

Input DataFrames:

```
print (df1)    
        A    B   C
0    John  236  76
1    Jack  204  74
2     Jim  156  71
3   Jared  182  72
4    Suzy  119  60
5   Sally  149  66
6  Sharon  169  65
7   Sammy  182  75

print (df2)
         A    B   C
0    Aaron  285  77
1      Abe  236  75
2     Alex  178  72
3     Adam  195  71
4     Mary  148  66
5   Maylee  155  66
6  Marilyn  199  65
7  Madison  160  73
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it with my data frames but it looks like that is what I needed to know! Thanks!  I also really appreciate Doom editing my question so it was easier to read.

Comment: I've tested it for the last hour and looked through the results trying to find anything wrong and can't.  This is incredibly helpful to me after I was so frustrated with it yesterday.  Thanks again.  My only change to make things clearer for me was to assign the gender column separately so that I could see easier (as a beginner) what exactly you were doing with the outer merge. THANKS!